# ¿Cómo crear dos formularios HTML que utilizando en Javascript puedan sumar y restar valores de forma independiente?

Tags: javascript, html

Estimados compañeros tengo un problema en cuanto a cómo crear varios formularios que sume y reste de forma independiente en javascript. poseo este código, la idea es poner mas 20 formularios que sean de forma independiente.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var total=0;
function sumar(valor) {
total += valor; 
document.formulario.total.value=total;
}
function restar(valor) {
total-=valor; 
document.formulario.total.value=total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name_1=formulario1>
<input name_1="checkbox" type="checkbox" onClick="if (this.checked) sumar(1); else restar(1)" value="checkbox">$1<br>
<input name_1="checkbox" type="checkbox" onClick="if (this.checked) sumar(2); else restar(2)" value="checkbox">$2<br>
<input type="text" name_1="total" value="0">
</form>
<form name=formulario2>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" onClick="if (this.checked) sumar(1); else restar(1)" value="checkbox">$1<br>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" onClick="if (this.checked) sumar(2); else restar(2)" value="checkbox">$2<br>
<input type="text" name="total" value="0">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Alexander, en primera no es necesario llenar tu HTML con etiquetas `<form></form>`, en segunda no puedes modificar el atributo `name=""` de las etiquetas del HTML, en tercer lugar el `value=""` del check debe contener un valor numérico si es que vas a hacer sumas y restas, no siendo así un `string`, creo que deberías de practicar o investigar más de html para que comprendas las etiquetas HTML y sus funciones.

Comment: Puedes crear **div's** con **id's** para que los puedas seleccionar con JS y tomar los valores de los `input` que estén dentro de ese `div` además de que puedes agregar _listener's_ a los `input`, evitando malas prácticas y evitando llenar de forma lineal tu HTML con JS.